# using ext.js in html file

Tags: html, extjs

I am new to ext.js and I need some explaination.
I wanto to use the ext.js features in a base html, without any use of html tags
I put the ext.js script tags in the html and I created an  Application.js file which I reference in the html itself and which contains a simple Ext.application (....) (taken from a sencha blog).
My question is, can I simply use ext.js by inserting the script libraries references in the html, or should I do something else beforehand ?
I saw the sencha cmd on the sencha site, but i suspect its just used to create the structre of the application itself , putting the right files in the right places.
Since I can't visualize anything  (apart from a js "alert" which I put at the beginning to seeif i call the right file), what am I doing wrong ?

This is my html :

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<link href='~/ExtJS/Content/Css/prova.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/ExtJs/Content/Css/ext-all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/ExtJs/Content/Css/ext-all-debug.css" />

<script src="~/ExtJS/Scripts/ext-all-dev.js"></script>
<script src="~/ExtJS/Scripts/ext-all.js"></script>
<script src="~/ExtJS/Scripts/ext-lang-it.js"></script>
<script src="~/ExtJS/Src/Application.js"></script>
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
```

This is my MVC layout file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - ExtJSApplication1</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
   
</head>
    
<body>
    <header>
        @*<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">ExtJSApplication1</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>*@
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - ExtJSApplication1 - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my Application.js file :

```
alert('launch');
Ext.application({
    launch: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'grid',
            title: 'Users',
            columns: [
                { text: 'Name', width: 100, dataIndex: 'name' },
                { text: 'Email Address', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'email' },
                { text: 'Phone Number', width: 200, dataIndex: 'phone' }
            ],
            data: data,
            listeners: {
                select: onSelect
            },
        });
    }
    }
);
function onSelect(sender, record) {
    var r = record[0].data;
    var text = r.name + ' - ' + r.email + ' - ' + r.phone;
    Ext.Msg.alert('Row Clicked', text);
};
var data = [
    { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
    { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
    { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
    { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to add ExtJS as a library instead of using it as a framework, you should do a build of the ExtJS abb beforehand and include the build files into your html.

**Framework Approach**

- Install Sencha CMD
- Start Windows PowerShell (or command line on your system)
- follow [this documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.4.0/guides/workspaces.html) to generate a workspace and an app
- Run `sencha app build production`
- Use the index.html from the build

If you need additional sources you can add them into the app.json file, that way all is loaded into the html file using ExtJS.

**Library Approach**

- same as above, but instead of using the ExtJS html...
- copy the `js` file and the `css` files into your own html (folder)

Answer (score 0):

how I did was:

1. use ExtJS gpl cdn. OR down load and store it locally
2. in extjs use renderTo: your_div_id ,// to render ext component on particular div

note: I have extjs license.